# Question on how to use the word help

Tags: american-english, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

> Can you help me **to update** the file？
>
> Can you help me **updating** the file？

Which one is correct?

A specific source of concern in the text is whether to use the -ing form or the infinitive?

Comment: Welcome to ELL, @Chochu . We hope we can help you with any other questions you have.

Answer (score 2):

Of the two choices, the first is perfect English and a clear expression of your wishes:

> Can you help me to update the file?

The verb **to help** is somewhat special in English. (See [this link](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/46931) if you would like to learn more.)  Most English speakers use the *bare infinitive* of a verb (the form of the infinitive without **to**) when it follows **help**:

> Can you help me update the file?

Your second choice, "Can you help me updating the file?" is also understandable English, and could even be interpreted as "correct," but it is not the best way to express your wishes. If you want to use the *gerund* of the verb **to update** in your sentence, instead of the *infinitive*, you could say:

> I need help *updating* the file.

Or:

> Can you help me *with updating* the file?

Comment: You might add that "Can you help me update the file?" is also OK. In fact I think it is the most natural one.